# Entity Framework translates all columns when using group by

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

When using the below LINQ to Sql expression,  it gets translated into SQL with **all columns** instead of only three (LocationId *order*, ArticleID *orderItem*, Qty *orderItem*).

```
var query = from orderItem in ctx.OrderItem
    join order in ctx.Order on orderItem.OrderID equals order.ID
    where order.Received == false
    group orderItem by new { order.LocationID, orderItem.ArticleID } into g
    select new
    {
        KEY = g.Key, /* contains LocationID and ArticleID only */
        SUM = g.Sum(p => p.Qty)
    };
```

I was expecting that only those are selected which are in the `select new { ... }` statement.

This is the translated output using SQL Profiler:

```
SELECT [orderItem].[ID], [orderItem].[ArticleID], [orderItem].[OrderID], [orderItem].[Price], [orderItem].[Qty], [order].[ID], [order].[Created], [order].[Currency], [order].[LocationID], [order].[Modified], [order].[Number], [order].[ROE], [order].[Received], [order].[Status], [order].[SupplierID], [order].[UserChangeID], [order].[UserID]
FROM [OrderItem] AS [orderItem]
INNER JOIN [Order] AS [order] ON [orderItem].[OrderID] = [order].[ID]
WHERE ([order].[Received] = 0)
ORDER BY [order].[LocationID], [orderItem].[ArticleID]
```

Any ideas on how to workaround this or why this is happening?

**Details: ASP.NET MVC Core, Entity Framework 7, MSSQL Server 2012 (11.0)**

Comment: That SQL's not doing the SUM() either. Is that definitely all the SQL being generated for this?

Comment: I don't see `GROUP BY` inside the SQL, so most likely EF is going to do the grouping in memory. Activate the logging and see what it shows, but frankly I would not use EF Core until it gets stable (and currently it isn't)

Comment: @IvanStoev can you please give me some references on how to do logging?

Comment: Also I know from my experience that not oonly EF7 but also EF6 and (maybe) lower have this problem of selecting all columns - How it come?

Comment: @EdPlunkett yes it is - Feel free to try yourself.

Comment: Nah, I'm all set, thanks.

Comment: What you put in the question obviously isn't exactly what is being run, as you have unbalanced parenthesis and it won't compile as is.

Comment: @RobertMcKee thank you.. fixed

Comment: At least the latest EF6 has no such issues. And separate database and memory execution of the query parts is EF Core concept. Here is [EF Core Logging](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/miscellaneous/logging.html) link.

Comment: I found an interessting comparision between EF Core and EF6 I want to share with all of you - https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/efcore-vs-ef6/features.html#side-by-side-comparison

Comment: It is a bug in entity framework, that i have reported in https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/5815